# Where iTunes stores my playlists and ratings

Tags: macos, itunes

I am wondering where iTunes keeps all my playlists? Locally on my computer or in the iCloud? I have created the new playlist on my Mac and I can see it on iPhone (without connecting it to MAC), so it looks like it is stored in iCloud. Is it right? Do I need to do something to backup them?

And the similar question about ratings. Where they are stored and how can I keep them between iTunes and Mac OS reinstallation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it stores the original on your computer.

The iCloud just gets a copy of it if you have set it up that way.

You can find the file in the `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl`

and in the `iTunes Music Library.xml` (located in same place)

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201610

Comment: Thanks. How can I set up iTunes to store the playlists in the iCloud?

Comment: Read this https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19610?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US